# Pasar el contendido de un objeto a mayúsculas

Tags: javascript, string

tengo un formulario que genera un objeto como este:

```
{
  "documento": 1,
  "origen": 0,
  "descripcion": "FUAR y/o sol. ind. con huella(s) ilegible en el área de solicitud",
  "resolucion": {
    "campo": true,
    "gabinete": false,
    "resguardo": false
  },
  "clave": "a1"
}
```

Este objeto lo mando a la función que realiza el envío POST a mi servidor, usando [axios](/questions/tagged/axios), muy simple, un mensaje en la consola y una alerta, por el momento.

```
let _createCausa = (_causa) => axios.post(`${BASEURL}/causas`, _causa)
  .then(_carga => {
    console.log(_carga)
    alert(`Se guardaron los siguientes datos: ${_carga.data.clave} - ${_carga.data.descripcion}`)
  })
  .catch(_error => {
    console.log(_error.response.data)
  })
```

Lo primero que hace la función es enviar los datos a la API `` (_causa) => axios.post(`${BASEURL}/causas`, _causa) ``, pero yo quisiera que antes de `axios.post()` los campos `descripción` y `clave` se pasarán a mayúsculas.

Pero, ¿cómo puedo convertir solo esos dos campos o propiedades, **antes** de guardarlos?

Comment: por que no los almacenas en una variable les aplicas un toUpperCase() y los envias?

Comment: @Rastalovely ¿podrías poner un ejemplo en una respuesta? Creo que se me acabaron las ideas.

Comment: @toledano No entiendo, qué problema habría con llevar a mayúsculas a `_causa.descripcion` y `_causa.clave`, y luego llamar a la función

Comment: @Mariano ¿si se puede? Creo que lo he hecho mal, porque solo obtengo errores. Voy a esperar si __Rastalovely__ pone una respuesta ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De preferencia mantén las funciones lo más puras que puedas, por lo tanto, evita **mutar** los parámetros. En su lugar, puedes clonarlo y sobreescribir las propiedades deseadas en el clon:

```
const createCausa = _causa => {
  const causa = Object.assign({}, _causa, {
    descripcion: _causa.descripcion.toUpperCase(),
    clave: _causa.clave.toUpperCase()
  });
  return axios.post(`${BASEURL}/causas`, causa);
}

async function sendCausa () {
  try {
    const response = await createCausa({ ... });
  } catch (e) {
    // manejar error
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 por clonar el objeto para evitar `mutaciones`

Comment: Gracias, todo funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías llamar a `toUpperCase()` sobre las propiedades `descripcion y clave` dentro de la función `_createCausa`.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
let _createCausa = (_causa) => {
  _causa.descripcion.toUpperCase()
  _causa.clave.toUpperCase()
  return axios.post(`${BASEURL}/causas`, _causa)
  .then(_carga => {
    console.log(_carga)
    alert(`Se guardaron los siguientes datos: ${_carga.data.clave} - ${_carga.data.descripcion}`)
  })
  .catch(_error => {
    console.log(_error.response.data)
  })
}
```